# How to enable export to HTML format at JasperReports Server

Tags: html, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need to export a report in HTML format with *JasperReports Server*. 
*JasperReport Server* provides options to export to several formats (pdf, xls, csv, docx, rtf, odt, ...) but HTML is not included.

[image: Exporter oprtions]

Export to HTML format is available in *iReport* preview, but not in the *JR Server* when I load a jrxml file.

What do I need to do or change to make the HTML export option available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option in *JasperReports Server* (I've checked the *6.2.0* and *5.5* versions).

You can check the *viewReportBeans.xml* configuration file placed in *WEB-INF\flows* folder.

It contains this block:

```xml
<util:map id="exporterConfigMap">
    <!-- comment/uncomment any of the lines below if you want related exporters 
         to be excluded/included in the viewer's exporters list
         Note: separate configuration for iPad 'exportersSupportedByiPad'
         -->

    <entry key="pdf" value-ref="pdfExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="xls" value-ref="xlsExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="xlsNoPag" value-ref="xlsNoPaginationExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="csv" value-ref="csvExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="docx" value-ref="docxExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="rtf" value-ref="rtfExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="odt" value-ref="odtExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="ods" value-ref="odsExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="xlsx" value-ref="xlsxExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="xlsxNoPag" value-ref="xlsxNoPaginationExporterConfiguration"/>
    <entry key="pptx" value-ref="pptxExporterConfiguration"/>
    <!-- 
    <entry key="txt" value-ref="txtExporterConfiguration"/>
    -->
</util:map>
```

You can disable some exporters here. But if you want to add the new one (*html* in your case) - you should change the source code of *JR Server* to add support of this format.

You can face some difficulties during implementation of *html* exporter for *JRS*. For example, how to handle images (external resource) in report.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Fortunately I found that performing a scheduling report generation, I can export to HTML format, which solves my problem.

I apologize for my English, which is not very fluid.

Regards.